# Python tranforming text to Xmas tree

Tags: python

Write a program that asks the user to enter a line of text and output it as a "Christmas tree".
for example
Input text: 5687341

7
873
68734
5687341

or any other text: hello how are you doing?

```
        r
       are 
     w are y
    ow are yo
   how are you 
  how are you d
o how are you do
```

lo how are you doi
llo how are you doin
ello how are you doing
hello how are you doing?

my code is:

```
text = str(input("Your text is: "))

print(text)

while text:

    text = text[1:-1]

    print((text)
```

but how to make as Xmas tree?

Comment: 1. You are printing the base of the tree first. Start with the top. 2. You need to print the correct amount of whitespace depending of which line of the tree you are on.

Comment: and how to do it?) plus pne more question, my Xmas tree should be from smallest element at the top to the the whole string. how to invert her

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tree for you! I'm not 100% certain this is what you were asking but I'm sure you can modify the code to better suit your needs if necessary.

```
text = str(input("Your text is: "))
for i in range(0, len(text) + 1, 2):
    offset = int((len(text) - i) / 2) 
    print(' ' * offset + text[offset:offset + i])
```

Basically for each row we want to print a number of whitespaces. This number is determined by taking the whole sentence and cutting it by half. The required whitespaces decrease each iteration (so `len(text) - i`). After the spaces we need to print an increasing number of characters from the original sentence starting from middle (hence 'offset').

Comment: thanks, but it does not delete the first element from each next string

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I updated the answer to reflect your feedback. I also widened the tree to include next two characters by setting the 'step' argument in the `range` function.

Comment: i am sorry, but i tried to put numbers as well, it does not work(
1234567

   34
 2345
123456

i am sure that it can be easier, cause on lessons we did not learn def draw_tree

Comment: That would be because the digits need to be inside quotation marks like "0123...". That makes it a string and not a big number. Or you can use `text = str(text)` inside the function, which will work even if you input numbers. I would strongly advise you to read up some basic tutorials on different variables and functions in Python. In short, `def draw_tree` is called a function definition and using it with `text` variable executes the content indented under the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can print a substring on each line with a matching indent.  The substring would start with the middle character and increase by one on each side for each new line:

```
s = "hello how are you doing"
for n in range(len(s)//2,-1,-1):
    print(" "*n+s[n:-n or None])

           r
          are
          are 
        w are y
       ow are yo
      how are you
      how are you 
    o how are you d
   lo how are you do
  llo how are you doi
 ello how are you doin
hello how are you doing
```

This doesn't look as good when you have an even number of characters though.  You could compensate by adding slashes at the begining and end of each level:

```
s = "hello how are you doing?"
for n in range(len(s)//2,-1,-1):
    print(" "*n+"/"+s[n:-n or None]+"\\")

            /\
           /re\
          /are \
         / are y\
        /w are yo\
       /ow are you\
      /how are you \
     / how are you d\
    /o how are you do\
   /lo how are you doi\
  /llo how are you doin\
 /ello how are you doing\
/hello how are you doing?\
```